# как проверить длину массива objective-c

Tags: массивы, objective-c, xcode

Имееться вот таков от JSON:

```
Response Body
[
  {
    "location": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Москва",
      "regionId": 977
    },
    "countries": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Болгария",
        "iso": "BG",
        "timeZone": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Россия",
        "iso": "RU",
        "timeZone": 4
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Таиланд",
        "iso": "TH",
        "timeZone": 7
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Турция",
        "iso": "TR",
        "timeZone": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Одесса",
      "regionId": 538
    },
    "countries": []
  }
]
```

Получаю и записываю Json в массив!

при записывании елементов JSON в переменные программа крашется!
Крашется на этапе записи пустого елемента ("countries": []);

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonSearchArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *lID = [[[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *lName = [[[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"name"];



        NSString *cID;
        if ([[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countries"] != NULL) {
            cID = [[[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countries"] objectForKey:@"id"];
        }
```

Что то не так вот в этой части кода!

```
NSString *cID;
            if ([[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countries"] != NULL) {
                cID = [[[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countries"] objectForKey:@"id"];
            }
```

Нужно сделать проверку на наличие обьекта!
ЕСЛИ обьект не путой ТО записываем обьект в пременную.
Подскажите что не так?

Comment: Может строка приходит просто пустая, попробуй if ([[[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countries"] isEqualToString:@""])

Comment: @ВикторМишустин countries в данном случае массив, как он может быть пустой строкой?

Comment: Проверить наличие объектов очень просто: [[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countries"] count] > 0

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае `[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countries"]` это массив словарей, к примеру если хочешь взять id первой страны, то это будет выглядеть так `NSNumber *firstCountryId = [[[jsonSearchArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"countries"] objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey:@"id"]`